# Unable to add a project to sourcetree

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to add a project that is in my documents on sourcetree but it displays in gray impossible to see in the file explorer of the software do you have a solution see image

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjvDm.png)
[finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3XrH.png)